# Spring reactor - eventbus hangs after processing some messages

Tags: spring, reactor

We use reactor, event bus in our project for event driven approach.

We are basically getting messages from Kafka and then delegating to reactor as below. This is working fine for few hundred messages and then hangs. I have added the code we use and have added the trace also.

Code which push messages to reactor ...

```
private static RingBufferWorkProcessor<TestEvent> processor =RingBufferWorkProcessor.<TestEvent> create("test", 128);

 processor.subscribe(testSubscriber);
  processor.onNext(testEvent);
```

TestSubscriber Class :-

```
@Component
public class TestSubscriber implements Subscriber<TestEvent> {
    private static Log log = new Log(TestSubscriber.class);

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(final Subscription s) {
        if (s != null) {
            s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(final TestEvent testEvent) {
        if (testEvent == null) {
            return;
        }
        getRootReactor().notify(testEvent.getType().getName(), Event.wrap(testEvent));
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final Throwable t) {
        if (t != null) {
            log.error(t.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        log.info("TestSubscriber is done.");
    }
}


public static EventBus getRootReactor() {
        if (rootReactor == null) {
            rootReactor = EventBus.create(Environment.get(), Environment.workDispatcher());
        }
        return rootReactor;
    }
```

Trace 1 :-

```
"pool-9-thread-1" prio=5 tid=63 TIMED_WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:338)
    at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.MultiProducerSequencer.next(MultiProducerSequencer.java:136)
    at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.MultiProducerSequencer.next(MultiProducerSequencer.java:105)
    at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer.next(RingBuffer.java:246)
    at reactor.core.dispatch.WorkQueueDispatcher.allocateTask(WorkQueueDispatcher.java:172)
    at reactor.core.dispatch.AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.java:118)
    at reactor.bus.EventBus.notify(EventBus.java:368)
       Local Variable: reactor.bus.Event#2
```

Trace 2 :-

```
"workQueueDispatcher-3" daemon prio=5 tid=42 TIMED_WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:338)
    at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.MultiProducerSequencer.next(MultiProducerSequencer.java:136)
    at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.MultiProducerSequencer.next(MultiProducerSequencer.java:105)
    at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer.next(RingBuffer.java:246)
    at reactor.core.dispatch.WorkQueueDispatcher.allocateTask(WorkQueueDispatcher.java:172)
    at reactor.core.dispatch.MultiThreadDispatcher.allocateRecursiveTask(MultiThreadDispatcher.java:59)
    at reactor.core.dispatch.AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.java:116)
    at reactor.bus.EventBus.notify(EventBus.java:368)
       Local Variable: reactor.bus.Event#6
```

I checked the reactor code where it is hanging and no clue on this.

```
@Override
112    public long More ...next(int n)
113    {
114        if (n < 1)
115        {
116            throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be > 0");
117        }
118
119        long current;
120        long next;
121
122        do
123        {
124            current = cursor.get();
125            next = current + n;
126
127            long wrapPoint = next - bufferSize;
128            long cachedGatingSequence = gatingSequenceCache.get();
129
130            if (wrapPoint > cachedGatingSequence || cachedGatingSequence > current)
131            {
132                long gatingSequence = Util.getMinimumSequence(gatingSequences, current);
133
134                if (wrapPoint > gatingSequence)
135                {
136                    LockSupport.parkNanos(1); // TODO, should we spin based on the wait strategy?
137                    continue;
138                }
139
140                gatingSequenceCache.set(gatingSequence);
141            }
142            else if (cursor.compareAndSet(current, next))
143            {
144                break;
145            }
146        }
147        while (true);
148
149        return next;
150    }
```

Thanks,